# How do I forcibly delete ALL xrandr/xinerama state and restore defaults?

Tags: xorg, display-resolution

**Background / Justification**

In Ubuntu 18.04, I'm having a totally off-the-wall issue that's not addressed by any other questions about xinerama or xrandr. Suddenly, my 4K monitor is frequently being treated as a 1440p monitor, with no option to set the resolution back to 4K. This problem tends to be triggered by monitor restarts or resolution changes (e.g. due to games). Once the problem starts, running either

```
xrandr -s 3840x2160
```

or doing the equivalent using `gnome-settings` causes the screen to black out for several seconds before silently returning to the incorrect `2560x1440` resolution. In particular, neither `xrandr` nor `dmesg` seem to show any error messages relevant to the problem. Furthermore, once triggered, the problem persists through a restart: the resolution is still low, and `xrandr 3840x2160` still silently fails. It seems the only way to solve the problem is to wait for a substantial amount of time for the problem to spontaneously resolve itself.

It's possible that the problem is a hardware issue, but I find this unlikely because:

1. 4K works fine when the resolution problem isn't triggered: still 60Hz, smooth, no distortion.
2. The problem does not occur in other operating systems, or on the gdm login screen (text appears at native resolution as far as I can tell). The resolution only resets to 1440p once the X session is actually started.
3. The problem can also be solved by plugging in a second 4K monitor, and using both -- but the problem reappears once the second 4K monitor is removed!

I suspect that something weird happened to xinerama's internal state -- I don't see why else I'm suddenly being plagued by these random resolution changes, barring hardware failures, which I find unlikely. So I want to delete / hard reset whatever files constitute xinerama's internal state.

**Actual Question**

I want to know the location of xinerama's config files (or more generally, its internal state) and forcibly reset them. You can try to xy-problem me but please look at the failed solutions first.

**Failed Solutions**

`xrandr -s 0` -- this command is often the answer to "how do I reset?" questions. This had the same effect as `xrandr -s 3840x2160`, i.e. nothing. I want to reset ALL state to try to fix the problem.

Restarting, as mentioned.

Manually adding `3840x2160` as a new mode. The problem is not that the monitor fails to report that as an option, but that `xrandr` mysteriously does nothing when that resolution is selected.

**Hardware/software details**

Kernel: 4.15.0-70-generic

Distro: Ubuntu 18.04

CPU: AMD Ryzen 2700X

GPU: AMD Vega 64

DE: GNOME 3

Monitor: Dell U2718Q

Comment: I'm tempted to delete `~/.config/monitors.xml`. I see a lot of suspicious `<width>2560</width>` entries, and I never manually set resolution to 1440p. Not sure if this alone could explain the weird behaviour though -- I would expect that even if X wrongly defaults to 1440p I should still be able to manually override it.

Comment: The problem just occured again, and I just shut down X and used the `Ctrl-Alt-F3` terminal to delete `~/.config/monitors.xml`. This instantly fixed the problem, unlike `xrandr -s 0`. Not sure if this will keep the problem away for good; will report again later.

Answer (score 0):

Removing `~/.config/monitors.xml` seems to have solved the problem for now. Said file was recreated later. I don't think that the file itself was the true problem -- rather it seemed to have triggered some underlying bug in `xrandr` (and it must be a bug -- no matter what, it makes no sense for `xrandr` to list `3840x2160` as an option and not support actually selecting that option). However, since the problem was solved for now, I don't feel like looking deeper into the true cause of the problem.